# FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server caused by idle timeout

Tags: php, debian, apache2, xenforo

Hi guys im having this issue on my server i get
Internal Server Error
afther i reach more than 550 users online on my xenforo forum im owning a powerfull Dell PowerEdge R530 server it comes w 32 core Xeon and 30 GB ram 2 TB SAS HDD.SO: Debian
this is all i get on error´s log:

> [Fri Mar 31 11:12:05.501829 2017] [fastcgi:error] [pid 7338:tid    140415189591808] [client 10.18.8.21:50388] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi", referer: http://10.16.1.1/forum/index.php?gallery/authors/la-cr-zy.46313/photos
>
> [Fri Mar 31 11:12:06.681752 2017] [fastcgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140415197984512] [client 10.24.5.196:1735] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec)
>
> [Fri Mar 31 11:12:06.681827 2017] [fastcgi:error] [pid 7818:tid 140415197984512] [client 10.24.5.196:1735] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"
>
> [Fri Mar 31 11:12:06.949759 2017] [fastcgi:error] [pid 7338:tid 140415231555328] [client 10.20.32.10:53003] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec)
>
> [Fri Mar 31 11:12:06.949864 2017] [fastcgi:error] [pid 7338:tid 140415231555328] [client 10.20.32.10:53003] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"
>
> [Fri Mar 31 11:12:07.225743 2017] [fastcgi:error] [pid 7573:tid 140415386834688] [client 10.24.60.79:59676] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec), referer: http://10.16.1.1/forum/